# creating new column on condition

Tags: r

I have 23 columns that are numeric but I am interested in one number only and other numbers would be coded as No. If the column contains number 3 it would be coded yes and other numbers would be no. How do I achieve that?
The df for demonstration.
thank you

```
id <- c(1:50)
c <- c(10:59)
d <- c(200:152, by=2)
e <- c(352:400, by=2)

df<-cbind.data.frame(id, c, d, c)
```

Comment: What does the `"by"` mean in `c()`?

Comment: use `which()` and `any()` for all of the columns individually

Comment: but that would take a lot of coding and texting. I would like to have something that could be used on the entire data frame and could be used on other dataframes later too. maybe something like a function

Comment: What would be your exact expected output given the input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to change values in `id` column i.e the 1st column you can do :

```
#Replace numbers that have 3 with "yes"
df[-1][sapply(df[-1], grepl, pattern = 3)] <- 'yes'
#Replace rest of the numbers with "no".
df[-1][df[-1] != 'yes'] <- 'no'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code needed some tweaks but I think this is what you had in mind:

```
id <- c(1:50)
c <- c(10:59)
d <- seq(200, 152, by = -2)
e <- seq(from = 452, to = 500, by=2)

df<-cbind.data.frame(id, c, d, e)
```

This gets the records with the letter "3"

```
df[stringr::str_detect(df$c, "3") | 
   stringr::str_detect(df$d, "3") |
   stringr::str_detect(df$e, "3") , ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `str_detect` with `case_when`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  set_names(make.unique(names(.))) %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, ~ case_when(str_detect(., '3') ~ 'yes', TRUE ~ 'no')))
```